# Java, not printing Chinese Character in Visual Studios Code, but works in Python

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, utf-8, formatting, output

When I do
System.out.println('说');
It just prints "?"

In the bottom right corner it says UTF-8 (so that is good).
I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any help much appreciated.
PS: When I make a python file and print it, it prints it properly. But not in java :(

I tried doing System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8"); but same result sadly. I tried running code in repl.it, and it works. But not in visual studios.

Note that windows Locale is set to support UTF-8. And I am using Consolas Font, which should support UTF-8.
I also tried uninstalling VS and installing it again - it didn't fix anything.

I am also using terminal for all output.

Comment: Which code page is being used (`chcp` command in command window)? Is your Windows Locale set to support Unicode UTF-8? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME3DG.png) {assuming Windows OS}

Comment: chcp is 65001 when done in the terminal.
I also have a thing where it auto does 65001 whenever I open to run code.
Json code online was used to automatically do the 65001:

Comment: Also I forgot to add, my Windows Locale is st to support Unicode UTF-8

Comment: What font is being used in your terminal window?

Comment: For font, this is what it says:
Editor: Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace
If I recall, Consolas can print special characters. For Terminal Font family it also says Consolas.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in VSCode on Windows 10. From this `System.out.println("PrintStream is using " + System.out.charset().toString() + ": " + '说'); ` I get this output in Terminal: `PrintStream is using UTF-8: 说`. Can you update your question to show your code, and also include my `println()` call so we can see what encoding is being used? You might also try doing `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));` to explicitly set your PrintStream to use UTF-8 before calling `println()`, though in your case that shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: Also provide a screen shot of the Terminal window to show _exactly_ what is being printed. I just ran in VSCode without doing any explicit configuration at all and it worked fine, so it seems probable that there is something in your environment that is causing this issue.

Answer (score -2):

What is your machine language? Change the system language to ***Chinese***, and modify the system locale to ***Chinese***(you may need to restart the computer), then restart vscode and print out Chinese characters.

[image]

Another simple and effective way is to use the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. Install the extension and execute the script with `Run Code`, the **OUTPUT** panel will display the result.

[image]

Comment: This is just wrong. You are telling the OP to _"Change the system language to Chinese, and modify the system locale to Chinese(you may need to restart the computer), then restart vscode"_ just to print a Chinese character in the output window?! The OP also states that _"windows Locale is set to support UTF-8"_, yet your  _"Region settings"_ screen shot shows that you are not doing that. My locale is _English(United States)_ and the character prints fine for me. The massive machine environment changes you propose just aren't necessary.